# Applying a filter in a Fluent NHibernate mapping using a lambda referencing an inherited property?

Tags: c#, fluent-nhibernate, mapping

Is there any way to specify in a fluent nhibernate mapping file a way to only conditionally pull values into a business entity?

My current mapping snippet is:

```
            HasMany(m => m.GroupUsers)
            .Table("GroupUsers")
            .KeyColumns.Add("UserEntityId")
            .Inverse()
            .Cascade.All();
```

Ideally, I'd like to have this (which compiles but throws a runtime error that gu isn't defined):

```
            HasMany(m => m.GroupUsers)
            .Table("GroupUsers")
            .KeyColumns.Add("UserEntityId")
            .Where(gu => gu.DeleteDate == null)
            .Inverse()
            .Cascade.All();
```

The crux of the issue is that I'd like the mapping to only pull back those group users entries with a null delete date.

Edit:  Delete date is on a base class

Comment: Is the `DeleteDate` property declared on the `GroupUser` class or on a base class? Because `Where()` with `Linq` has some limitations... However you can always fall back to string `.Where("DeleteDate is NULL")`

Comment: DeleteDate is declared on a base class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the FluentNhibernate [API documentation](http://fluentnhibernate.org/api/FluentNHibernate.Mapping/ToManyBase%603.htm#Where):

> T Where(Expression> where)
>
> Sets the where clause for this one-to-many relationship. Note: This
>   only supports simple cases, use the string overload for more complex
>   clauses.

It seems **filtering for base class properties** is belongs to the "complex" cases.

So you should use the `Where(String)` overload (I haven't tested the syntax...):

```
HasMany(m => m.GroupUsers)
            .Table("GroupUsers")
            .KeyColumns.Add("UserEntityId")
            .Where("DeleteDate is null")
            .Inverse()
            .Cascade.All();
```

Comment: It didn't work because DeleteDate is on the base table, but it's good to know this in the future should I need to filter on a value.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and since I didn't believe this should be a "complex" case I ended up changing one line in the FluentNH source code which resolved it. I made a pull request but until it gets merged (or if it doesn't get merged at all) you can build it from here: https://github.com/alexDevBR/fluent-nhibernate/

EDIT: It was merged.