# Using a null in where clause of rnHibernate

Tags: c#, fluent-nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I am trying to filter out the result in the mapping. However I am trying to filter out the nulls from an int field. nHiberate throw an exception. If I use an number it works. Here is the code:

```
table("products");
            Id(x => x.productID);
            Map(x => x.canOverwrite);           
            Map(x => x.format);
            Map(x => x.freeShipping);
            Map(x => x.height);           
            Map(x => x.lastUpdated);
            Map(x => x.length);           
            Map(x => x.releaseDate);
            Map(x => x.removeDate);                       
            HasMany(x => x.ProductContributors).Where(c => c.sortID != null).KeyColumn("productID").Not.LazyLoad();
```

Any suggestions on how to get to this to work?

Comment: Is `sortID` a nullable int? If not, perhaps check for the value `0` (assuming `0` isn't a valid non-null value)

Comment: It is nullable. Basically if we want the contributor to be in a sort order we assign a value. If we disable the contributor, then it is null. I think I have another solution, filtering by the disabled column (bool). Then I can only get the ones that are enabled, thus getting the same result as I was after.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Applying a filter in a Fluent NHibernate mapping using a lambda referencing an inherited property?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9689953/applying-a-filter-in-a-fluent-nhibernate-mapping-using-a-lambda-referencing-an-i)

Answer (score 0):

In the contributors I also had a bool value for disabled. I added that to the entity and mapping. Then I filtered by disabled == false. Not really a solution and more of a work around.